# XSLT: How to exclude certain html tags from xml string?

Tags: xslt, tridion

I'm trying to exclude certain set of html tags from the xml string using XSLT 1.0

Here, currently I'm excluding `<a>` and `<img>` tag. For `<a>` tag, I want to display only text.

### Tried XSLT template:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="ExcludeHTMLTags">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'a' or local-name() = 'img'">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

### Calling above template in the below fashion:

```
<xsl:variable name="guideContent">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates 
 select="document(@guideID)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:GeneralContent/em:Body/node()" 
 mode="expandXHTML"/>
  </root>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($guideContent)/node()" mode="ExcludeHTMLTags"/>
```

### Input XML string:

```
<root>
This is a test message.
<p>Message within p tag</p> click <a href="www.test.com">here</a>.
<img src="/test.jpg" /> Message after image.
<strong>Message within strong</strong>
<link:component id="XXX" ... >My Link</link:component>
<p>Message after link component</p>
</root>
```

### OUTPUT:

```
<root>
This is a test message.
<p>Message within p tag</p> click here.
Message after image.
<strong>Message within strong</strong>
<link:component id="XXX" ... >My Link</link:component>
<p>Message after link component</p>
</root>
```

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong and tell the best way.

Comment: Please, provide a source XML document and the exact wanted result.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I have updated the sample input and expected output.

Comment: Siva Charan -- Again this is very malformed. Anyway, I have answered your question, using wellformed (x)Html.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: To make well formed, I can wrap a root node. So there won't be problem I guess.

Comment: Siva Charan, It is still malformed -- don't you have a proper XML editor/IDE to see this immediately?

Comment: Hi Siva, as someone working with SDL Tridion can I suggest you join/commit to the site on Area51? You can find it at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=nXVQ8p1hREONn9xqeeO2NA2

Comment: @JeremyGrand-Scrutton: Hi Jeremy, I'm already joined and committed at the initial phase itself.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't see you in the list of committers, must have msised you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="img"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (none provided by the OP !!!):

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a>Anchor text</a>
  <img source="http://someUrl"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<html>
   <body>Anchor text</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have one doubt, actually am already using `node()|@*` template match for initial checks. Now i can't use the same match. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @SivaCharan, Please, just copy and paste this code and run it -- this is the simplest and most direct way to verify it's working.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. It seems working as expected. I have changed my template based on your inputs and now am testing on it. Once I complete all round of testing, I will update the status to you and accept the answer.